# Simple Cryptocurrency, variables (str, int, global) pretty easy to fix, just don't know what function it is

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I was trying to make a simple cryptocurrency program in python(not block-chain) and I was having a lot of trouble with the variables, can you please help!!! (I'm a beginner) I'm not worried about security in the code, All the variables are messed up, like the global and the int and str. I have enough experience to do this. What the program is supposed to do is create a starting balance of one, and then the user enters their name, and a file is created, containing their balance and username, then they can select from mining and sending(I have not programmed that yet), when they mine, the program waits for 3 seconds, then it adds one to their balance and the file is updated, but the problem is that when the mine it does not do that, and also it always resets back to one. It needs to save so that you can go back and have the same balance and also be able to mine.

```
import os
import time




balance = -1

user = input("Username:")
f = open(user + "'s file", "w")

userbalance = f'{user} {balance}'
username = f'{user}'
ubalance = f'{balance}'
log = f'{username} has a balance of {ubalance} Coinon'


f = open(user + "'s file", "a")
f.write(str(log))
f.close()

os.system("clear")


print("Your Current Balance Is " + (str(ubalance)) + " Coinon")

print("Mine = 1")
print("Send = 2")
options = input("Selection:")



if options == "1":
 os.system("clear")
 for x in range(3):
  time.sleep(3)
  ubalance = balance + ubalance
  f = open(user + "'s file", "a")
  f.write(str(log))
  f.close()
  print("Your Current Balance Is " + (str(ubalance)) + " Coinon")
  print("mine success")

pass
```

Comment: `ubalance = balance + ubalance` attempts to add the integer `balance` to the string `ubalance`, which is a `TypeError` in Python. Why is `ubalance` a string anyway and how is it different from `balance`?

Comment: I tried to make balance the starting point to be able to create ubalance and then I tried to add balance to ubalance so that it would be -1 plus the users balance to see if the balance would change it was originally ubalance = ubalance +1

Comment: `ubalance` is a string, because of `ubalance = f'{balance}'`. It's not possible to add a number to a string. Also, logically, the balance should be a number.

Comment: how could I make it a normal varible, but also be able to use it in all the places i did?

Comment: You can simply write `ubalance = balance'` instead of `ubalance = f'{balance}'`

Comment: this does not work 


**  balance = 1

user = input("Username:")
f = open(user + "'s file", "w")

userbalance = '' + user + balance
username = user
ubalance = balance
log = '' + username + 'has a balance of' + ubalance + "coinon" **

Comment: That's the same problem: `'has a balance of' + ubalance + 'Coinon'` attempts to add the integer `ubalance` to the string `'has a balance of'`. You can use f-strings: `f'has a balance of {ubalance} Coinon'`

Comment: it stll keeps the same balance

Comment: It works perfectly now except for it keeps reseting the balance back to 1          balance = 1

user = input("Username:")
f = open(user + "'s file", "w")

username = user
ubalance = balance
userbalance = f'{balance}{username}'
log = f'{user} has a balance of {ubalance} Coinon'

Comment: `open(user + "'s file", "w")` at the beginning of the script opens the file in write mode, which clears the file first

Comment: so do i do "a"? I need a file created if there is none but also not overwrite if there is

Comment: Well, you can write code to do this: if (file exists): open it in `"a"` mode; else: open in `"w"` mode

Comment: how would i open a users file? import user + "'s balance.py" like rtm's balance.py

Comment: `open(user + "'s file", "r")`?

Comment: I mean like to import the balance from a file, "rtm's balance.py" and use that to display the amount of coins the person has

Comment: This looks like a different question. There should be many tutorials about loading data from a file

Comment: Please go through a [beginners guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) if you want to learn how to program with python :)